# How to retrieve a value from an array inside of a JSON object using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, java-8, jackson

Simply put, how do I retrieve {"value1":123"} using Jackson in a non-chaining way?

```
{
  "aaa": [
      {
        "value1": "123"
      }
  ],
  "bbb": [
      {
          "value2": "456"
      }
  ]
}
```

I tried using:
`jsonNode.at("/aaa[Array][0])` but i get missing node in response.

Any help would be good.

Comment: Use `ObjectMapper` `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Map<String,Object>> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, Map.class);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading value of nested key in JSON with Java (Jackson)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858248/reading-value-of-nested-key-in-json-with-java-jackson) see the first answer here

Answer (score 9):

The correct json path expression would be "/aaa/0/value1"

Use:

```java
jsonNode.at("/aaa/0/value1")
```

Comment: This works OK, but what is the function of the `/0/` in between the nodes? My subfield is not the first index, still this works

Comment: `aaa` is a json array, so it has to be followed by an index.

Answer (score 1):

use this below code :

```
    JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
    System.out.println(node.path("aaa").get(0)); // {"value1":"123"}
```

1. use [jackson-databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.6).
2. use this

   > node.path("aaa").get(0).get("value1") // 123.

Answer (score 1):

Using node.path("aaa").get(0) is what retrieved the first item from array. Any other ideas like node.path("aaa[0]") or node.path("aaa/0") do not work.

Comment: the question specifically asked for a way of doing it `in a non-chaining way`. Although what you are saying there is correct, and you can definitely do it that way. It is outside of the scope of the question.