# How do I cleanly drill down through nested object in Java?

Tags: java, list, for-loop

I have the following Java class:

```
public class MyClass{

    private List<Settings> settings;

    public static class Settings {
        private String name;
        private List<Features> features;
    }

    public static class Features {
        private String name;
        private Boolean isActive;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is first check that `settings` is not null or empty. If not, then I want to find the `Settings` object that has the name "reliability", and then find its `Features` objects that have the names "logs" and "score" and get the `isActive` from these two objects.

This is what I've tried:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass ();
Boolean logs = false;
Boolean score = false;

if (myClass.getSettings != null) {
    for (Settings setting: myClass.getSettings) {
        if (setting.getName().equals("reliability")) {
            for (Features features : setting.getFeatures) {
                if (features.getName().equals("logs")) {
                    logs = features.getIsActive;
                } else if (features.getName().equals("score")) {
                    score = features.getIsActive;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do this in a clean way? I can only do it with countless nested if and for loops, and it is not pretty.

Comment: Convert the JSON to a Java class (you'll get an object), then do your manipulations on it

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran It is a Java Class

Comment: No brother, it is a JSON body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you query object collections in Java (Criteria/SQL-like)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93417/how-do-you-query-object-collections-in-java-criteria-sql-like)

Comment: What you have shown above is JSON text - so basically a String - right?  So you are asking how you can extract individual fields from that String - yes?   If so, do NOT attempt to write your own parser, but instead use an established library like Jackson, that does the parsing and provides functions for data extraction - eg, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29901800/681444

Comment: @racraman No that was just to explain the structure, I've edited it so you can see the class now.

Comment: Ah ok, that’s much clearer.  One suggestion : never let your List be null.  If there are no Settings, let it be an empty list - the functionality remains the same, but you can confidently remove the `if != null` check.  You achieve this by setting the instance variable `private List<Settings> settings = new ArrayList<>();`, and also have the `setSettings` method (if you have one) pick up if `null` is being passed in.

Comment: So you need to extract two `boolean` values from the list of `MyClass` object? BTW way are you using wrapper type `Boolean`, is it imply that these properties might be `null`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it should be specifically those two `boolean` values.

Comment: *I can only do it with countless nested if and for loops, and it is not pretty.*  I wouldn't say two for loops is countless.  And if you had  some unknown nesting level you would probably need to use recursion.  If the above worked for you, there is nothing wrong with the way you did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the possible solution with Streams.

I assume that there would be no duplicated `Features` (i.e. having the same `name`) objects.

*By the way, class names are usually singular nouns. Class `Features` is meant to represent a single object with a distinct name and a single property `isActive`. Therefore, the name `Feature` might` be more suitable.*

The method below expects an argument of type `MyClass`, settings name and *varargs* of names of target features. The result it produces is `Map` with feature names as keys and corresponding `isActive` properties as values.

```
public static Map<String, Boolean> getFeaturesByName(MyClass myClass,
                                                     String settingName,
                                                     String... featureNames) {
    
    if (myClass.getSettings() == null) return Collections.emptyMap();
    
    Set<String> featureSet = Set.of(featureNames);
    
    return myClass.getSettings().stream()
        .filter(settings -> settings.getName().equals(settingName))
        .flatMap(settings -> settings.getFeatures().stream())
        .filter(features -> featureSet.contains(features.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            MyClass.Features::getName,
            MyClass.Features::getActive
        ));
}
```

Comment: Where do you filter settings with name "reliability"?

Comment: @Ben Sorry, missed it. Applied additional `filter`.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran settings.getFeatures() can not be null. Either the whole thing is null or or none of it is. I've even eliminated the possibility of  settings being null as 
racraman suggested in the OP.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Learn about the [**YAGNI principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). Don't invent the requirements that are not specified.

Answer (score 1):

Delegate the "drilling" to your classes:

add to `MyClass`

```
public boolean hasSettings() {
    return settings != null && !settings.isEmpty();
}

public Settings getSetting(String name) {
    return settings.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.hasName(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No settings with name " + name));
}
```

add to `Settings`

```
public boolean hasName(String name) {
    return this.name.equals(name);
}

public Features getFeature(String name) {
    return features.stream()
            .filter(f -> f.hasName(name))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("No feature with name " + name));
}
```

add to `Features`

```
public boolean hasName(String name) {
    return this.name.equals(name);
}
```

Then you can do

```
if (myClass.hasSettings()) {
    Settings reliabilitySetting = myClass.getSetting("reliability");
    logs = reliabilitySetting.getFeature("logs").isActive();
    score = reliabilitySetting.getFeature("score").isActive();
}
```

**NOTE:** You can return `Optional`s if you don't want to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Well to check if the object is nullable or not you can use the optional class then regarding of find the setting object you have an option to use Java Stream Filter to filter the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream API to reduce the code

```
private static final String SETTINGS_NAME_FOR_CHECK = "reliability"; 
private static final List<String> FEATURES_NAME_FOR_CHECK = Arrays.asList("logs", "score"); 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

    if(myClass.getSettings() != null) {

        Settings correctSettings = myClass.getSettings().stream()
                .filter(setting -> SETTINGS_NAME_FOR_CHECK.equals(setting.getName()))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);

        if(correctSettings.getFeatures() != null) {
            List<Features> features = correctSettings.getFeatures().stream()
                    .filter(feature -> (FEATURES_NAME_FOR_CHECK.contains(feature.getName()))).collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(features);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you get the `features` (which will be only having logs and shares), you can check for the boolean value.

Comment: This is not what op asked for. getSettings().stream() can throw a nullpointer, and the result should be a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code cleaner you can move logic into support methods.  This also makes it more testable.  In your code you are inspecting an instance of MyClass to determine if it certain features which are identified by name.  You could write a method that does just that.  Your original code could be re-written as:

```
MyClass myClass = ...
boolean hasLogs = hasSettingFeature(myClass, "reliability", "logs");
boolean hasScore = hasSettingFeature(myClass, "reliability", "score");
```

You can iterate through the given instance within the support model.  You can do with this for-loops.

```
public boolean hasSettingFeature(MyClass myClass, String settingName, String featureName) {
  if (null == myClass || null == myClass.getSettings()) {
    return false;
  }
  for (Settings settings : myClass.getSettings()) {
    if (settingName.equals(settings.getName()) {
      for (Features features : settings.getFeatures()) {
        if (featureName.equals(features.getName()) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You may also use the Stream API to filter to determine the state:

```
public boolean hasSettingFeature(MyClass myClass, String settingName, String featureName) {
  if (null == myClass || null == myClass.getSettings()) {
    return false;
  }
  return myClass.getSettings().stream()
      .filter(setting -> settingName.equals(setting.getName()))
      .flatMap(setting -> setting.getFeatures())
      .filter(features -> featureName.equals(features.getName()))
      .findAny()
      .isPresent();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, a more fitting datastructure would be the `Map`. I presume every `Features` exists only once?

```
public class MyClass {

    private Map<String, Settings> settings;

    public static class Settings {
        private String name;
        private Map<String, Features> features;
    }

    public static class Features {
        private String name;
        private Boolean isActive;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass t = new MyClass();
        Boolean logs = null, score = null;
        Settings s = t.settings.get("reliability");
        if (s != null) {
            Features f;
            if ((f = s.features.get("logs")) != null) // Is "features" null-save?
                logs = f.isActive;
            else if ((f = s.features.get("score")) != null)
                score = f.isActive;
        }
        System.out.println("Logs: " + logs + ", Score: " + score);
    }
}
```

(Also it is very bad practice to use the nullable wrapperclass Boolean. You might wanna do something about that.)

If you have problems turning your existing lists into maps, use this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Settings> map = toMap(List.of(new Settings()), s -> s.name);
}

static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Collection<V> c, Function<V, K> func) {
    return c.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(func, v -> v));
}
```